# SQLite - How to make more smaller databases in order to get better performance?

Tags: php, performance, sqlite

Is there some class or method to limit the size or the number of records in a SQLite database and automatically create a new DB once first one is full (up to limit)?

My SQLite DB can go up to 500mb in size and on shared hosting it won't work.
So, I want to divide it to 10 databases of 50 MB or so.

Will this also allow to easily read from the right database if several of them are created?

Comment: This sounds incredibly painful (especially once you start dealing with JOINs). Get better hosting instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to open other databases inside one session with the [`ATTACH` command](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html):

```sql
ATTACH '/data/db1.sqlite' AS db1; -- opens or creates that file
ATTACH '/data/db2.sqlite' AS db2;

CREATE TABLE db1.customers(...);
CREATE TABLE db2.product(...);
CREATE TABLE main.orders(...);    -- "main" is the connection's default database

SELECT * FROM customers, orders WHERE orders.custid = customers.id ...
                                  -- table names are searched for in all DBs
```

However, it is not possible to automatically split a database; each table (and its indexes) must be stored completely inside one file.
If most of your data is inside one table, this won't help you at all.